# Inserindo dados gerados em code behind através do model sem ter que EXIBIR no view, é possível?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Olha eu vou começar dizendo que eu sei q eu oque eu to tentando fazer é quebrar um tabu do padrão MVVM, mas não é possível que não exista outra modo de fazer isso, é comum ter q criar variáveis novas no background da aplicação e ter q envia-las pro servidor.

Sendo bem direto eu estou usando um timpespan que funciona por um EventHandler para ser meu temporizador que é exibido por um periodo de tempo, para ter mais facilidade de inserir esse valor no servidor pensei em fazer um conversor de tempo que transformasse tudo em minuto e mandasse pro servidor como sendo Int32 a cada um minuto, através de outro timespan que é ativado a cada um minuto:

ConvertTemp.cs

```
public static int ConvertTemp(string value)
       {
           DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
           int val = temp.Hour*60 ;

           return val + temp.Minute;
       }
```

A partir desse momento eu tenho a existência de uma nova variável no code behind do xaml.cs (view), a mesma está contextualizada no .cs(ViewModel) porém a única forma de inserção no servidor que eu encontrei (não tenho certeza se é realmente a única forma) foi através do binding (associação de dados) via View, isso significa que para que tenha o envio ao servidor pelo Modelo eu tenho que criar um elemento na visualização, associa-lo via Binding com a variavel e capacitar o envio de dados através do Mode=TwoWays. Ficou assim:

XAML

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding US_01TIM_CPM_01, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="TIM_CPM_01"/>
```

Eu ainda tentei usar o `converter={staticResouce ConvertTemp}` porem ele não funcionou (eu fiz todo o role do override e `: ValueConverter<string, int>` na classe do ConverTemp e não rolou) e tive q fazer a chamada no Event handler a cada um minuto assim:

```
 private void t_Minute(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Binding binding = new Binding("Text");
            //binding.Source = TIM_COP_01.Text;
            //TIM_CPM_01.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
            TIM_CPM_01.Text = ""+Data.ConvertTemp.ConvertT(TIM_COP_01.Text);
        }
```

Eu vou deixar os comments pra voces terem ideia do que eu já tentei, agradeço desde já galera!